# how can I test a WCF service using XAMPP to work with Apache server?

Tags: wcf, xampp, virtual-machine, htdocs, wcftestclient

I built a WCF service on a windows virtual machine, and tested it with the WCF test client by typing this on my browser:

```
http://localhost/Service1.svc/getAllCustomers
```

... and it works pretty good. Now the problem is that I want to do the same test in my real computer (not the VM).

I'm using XAMPP on the VM, I have set the project on the `htdocs` folder, and I type this on my browser:

```
http://10.211.55.3/WCFWebService/Service1.svc.cs/getAllCustomers
```

The problem is that it doesn't return the result of calling `getAllCustomers`, instead it returns the `Service1.svc.cs` in plain text.

I want it to do the same thing it does on the VM - can someone tell me what the problem is? I think it's because on the VM it works with the WCF test client, and since my computer is a Mac I can't run the WCF test client.

Answer (score 0):

A WCF service can't run on an Apache web server instead you should install IIS Server on the VM in order to test the service.
Refer to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

Comment: thanks I didn't know that, I'm working with IIS now alhtough it's giving me some troubles to configure it

Answer (score 0):

I found this with a Google query.

I kept the tab open, but continued exploring the other search results.

One I found particularly interesting was this one: [WCF acting as Web Service without IIS](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/689981-wcf-acting-web-service-without-iis)

It appears WCF gives options other than IIS to host the web service (Console Application, Windows Application, Windows Services).

The Windows Service link is provided here: [How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.100).aspx)

I have not done this, so I cannot elaborate on what problems you will run into.

I just want others that may run into this (like I did) to know that the one answer posted last year may not actually be the end of the road.